# Android Show Internal Data in to textviews

Tags: java, android, internal

I am working on an app where I need to save/read my files from Internal storage.
But it read all my data in the same TextView.
Can someone show me show,how to show the data in 2 textviews, or to show me how put the one data under the other data.

Here is my code for saving data:

```
private void SaveMode() {

            String FILENAME ;
            String Strin1= textview1.getText().toString();
            String String2= textview2.getText().toString();


            EditText filename1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename);

            FILENAME = filename1.getText().toString();
            if (FILENAME.contentEquals("")){
                FILENAME = "UNTITLED";
            }



            String1 = textview1.getText().toString();
            String2= textview2.getText().toString();

            FileOutputStream fos = null;


            try {
                fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.write("Strin1.getBytes()); 
                fos.write(String2.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   


            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And here is my code for read my data:

```
private void getFilenames() {
    String[] filenames = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<filenames.length; i++){
        //Log.d("Filename", filenames[i]);
        list.add(filenames[i]);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
}

public void SpinnerClick(View v) {

    String selectFile = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
    openFile(selectFile);

}

private void openFile(String selectFile) {

    showData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data);
    TextView showData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data1);
    String value = "";
    FileInputStream fis;


    try {
        fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(input) != -1){

            value += new String(input);
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    showData.setText(value);        
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to edit my read code like this, but with no luck

```
private void openFile(String selectFile) {

    TextView showData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data);
    TextView showData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data2);
    String value = "";      
    String[] strArray =  value.split(";");

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(input) != -1){


            value += new String(input);
        }

        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    showData.setText(value);
    showData.setText(strArray[0]);
    showData2.setText(strArray[1]);
}
```

**Edit 2**

Got it to work with Shobhit Puri codes

Comment: You can devide the data/string using a delimiter if you want. Then you can use the two splitted string to show into two text views. You migh have to take care of it during saving as well.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean in code

Comment: You should click the green tick to accept the answer; not edit in the words "solved".

Answer (score 1):

First while saving your data you might insert a delimiter in between those two string. Make sure that delimiter is not the one expected in your textViews.

While saving:

```
String string3 = ";";

try {
    fos.write("Strin1.getBytes()); 
    fos.write("String3.getBytes()); 
    fos.write(String2.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then when you are trying to read it into `value` string, then split is using `.split` function. Eg:

```
String[] strArray =  value.split(";");
```

`strArray[0]` will give first textview's sting and `strArray[1]` will give the second.

**Update**

```
private void openFile(String selectFile) {

    TextView showData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data);
    TextView showData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_data2);
    String value = "";      

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(input) != -1){


            value += new String(input);
        }

        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] strArray =  value.split(";");

    showData.setText(strArray[0]);
    showData2.setText(strArray[1]);
}
```

Comment: Will you please give me an example with the .split function

Comment: I think the second part talk about that, by using `value.split(";");`.

Comment: Will you please show me how this value.split(";"); code works

Comment: [.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is an in-built function, which splits the string based on the delimiter regex. So, wherever it will find `;` in above code, it will split the string from there into the String array.

Comment: Thank I know what you mean now, but i dont know where to put the .split() code. where should i put it under the read code.

Comment: You can put it before `showData.setText(value);`. So after doing split, you can do something like `showData1.setText(strArray[0]);` and `showData2.setText(strArray[1]);` for two text views that you might have.

Comment: I have edit my code and know it dosent work. will you please take  look at it and fix my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                    BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     myData = myData + strLine;
                }
                    in.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   myInputText.setText(myData);
```